# How to do login at end of other form submission in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I'm writing a web app where you can make a product request through a form before logging in (or signing up).  It's kind of a "try it" mode to get the abandon rate lower.  When we were putting the signup first -- we were way too many people abandoning the service because they had to make an account first.  This way we're drawing people committing some effort before they have to signup.

In any case, I am having trouble getting this pattern working.  I'm using the flask-login extension.  I have a view that renders my product request form and redirects to the login view if the user is not logged in:

```
@app.route('/customer/gift_request', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# Note login is NOT required for this.
def gift_request():
    form = GiftRequestForm()
    error = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if current_user.get_id():
            new_gift_request = GiftRequest(
                current_user.id,
                form.giftee_name.data,
                form.giftee_age.data,
                int(form.giftee_sex.data),
                form.event.data,
                form.event_date.data,
                float(form.budget.data))
            try:
                db.session.add(new_gift_request)
                db.session.commit()
                flash("You have successfully submitted a gift request! ",'success')
                return redirect(url_for('customer_home'))
            except:
                error = "Error creating gift request"
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url)

    return render_template('customer_portal/gift_request.html', form=form, error=error)
```

My login view is the following:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    error = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            if bcrypt.hashpw(form.password.data.encode('utf-8'), user.password.encode('utf-8')) == user.password:
                login_user(user)
                flash('User {} logged in'.format(current_user.email), 'success')

                # Handle the next URL
                next_url = request.args.get('next')
                if next_url is not url_for('gift_request'):
                    return abort(400)

                return redirect(next_url or url_for('customer_home'))
            else:
                error = "Incorrect password"
        else:
            error = "User not found"
    return render_template("user/landing_page.html",
                       login_form=form,
                       register_form=RegisterForm(),
                       error=error,
                       show_login_modal=True,
                       show_register_modal=False)
```

Note that my login is rendered as a modal window on my landing page.  In any case, I have no idea how to keep my gift request form data around after the login.  How do I pass that around?  I've tried a bunch of stuff -- like putting it in the request -- but that feels hacky (and potentially insecure).  Also, upon login submission -- that form data is gone. It's never passed to the login template, so i guess it just disappears.  I've searched the internet, but I can't seem to find a pattern to do this.

Also, the login is just a piece of this -- if the person that's filling out the gift request doesn't have a login, then I want to take them to the registration page to make an account.  But I figure if I figure this out -- I can take the same pattern and extend it to that.

Comment: Do I have to use a session here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may need to use a session. It would look something like this:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
    if current_user.get_id():
        session['new_gift_request'] = GiftRequest(
            current_user.id,
            form.giftee_name.data,
            form.giftee_age.data,
            int(form.giftee_sex.data),
            form.event.data,
            form.event_date.data,
            float(form.budget.data))
```

I have used this many times, and I've never had an issue. If you want the form data to hang around without a session, then you have to keep track of it and pass it to every subsequent template.

UPDATE

After re-reading your code it appears that if the current user is not logged in, you aren't saving the form data at all. Here is a slight change (obviously make sure you import session from flask):

```
@app.route('/customer/gift_request', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
# Note login is NOT required for this.
def gift_request():
    form = GiftRequestForm()
    error = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if current_user.get_id():
            new_gift_request = GiftRequest(
                current_user.id,
                form.giftee_name.data,
                form.giftee_age.data,
                int(form.giftee_sex.data),
                form.event.data,
                form.event_date.data,
                float(form.budget.data))
            try:
                db.session.add(new_gift_request)
                db.session.commit()
                flash("You have successfully submitted a gift request! ",'success')
                return redirect(url_for('customer_home'))
            except:
                error = "Error creating gift request"
        else:
            session['giftee_name'] = form.giftee_name.data
            session['giftee_age'] = form.giftee_age.data
            session['giftee_age'] = form.giftee_age.data
            session['giftee_sex'] = int(form.giftee_sex.data)
            session['event'] = form.event.data
            session['event_date'] = form.event_date.data
            session['budget'] = float(form.budget.data)
            return redirect(url_for('login', next=request.url)

    return render_template('customer_portal/gift_request.html', form=form, error=error)
```

Comment: Ok this almost works.  Writing to a session isn't working out of the box with WTForms. I'm trying to just persist the form or form.data. Neither works. I get: TypeError: Decimal('343434') is not JSON serializable.  I'm just doing `session['gift_request_form'] = form.data`

Comment: I think that error is not related to your initial problem. Try adding your form data separately like `session['variable_name'] = form.variable_name.data` that is how I have always seen it done. I cannot find any documentation of using form.data like that.